# Is there anything wrong with the sentence "Donuts are not a part of healthy eating"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

The sentence in question is:

> Donuts are not a part of healthy eating.

I'm debating between the following:

1. Nothing wrong
2. Donuts are not part of healthy eating (because "donuts" is plural, is it grammatical for "*a* part" to follow? Or does this not matter?)

Comment: I think the mistake is the inclusion of the word *not* in the sentence, but that's a semantic error, not a grammatical one.

Comment: The subject and the verb must agree, regardless of what’s on the other side of them (cf. *The problem is the horses.*)

Comment: I have a personal quirk that forbids me to say "healthy diet" instead of "healthful diet".

Comment: Putting aside the grammar, it’s factually inaccurate. Donuts can be a part of healthy eating - just not very many of them.

Comment: the spelling of doughnuts? :p

Answer (score 8):

My main quibble is with the term *eating*, in medical and self-help literature, *diet* is preferable.

> Donuts (doughnuts) are not **part of a healthy *diet***

Google Books: [“part of a healthy diet”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22part+of+a+healthy+diet%22&sca_esv=562581159&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBiX8cB4wsBf-zPx5nxwxtL8XoHp4A:1693854587743&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtqoOI1JGBAxXk0QIHHWhyDMQQ0pQJKAR6BAgCEAc&biw=1117&bih=632&dpr=2.5)

> - *Including foods rich in omega-3 fatty acids **as part of a healthy diet** may help reduce inflammation*.
> - … *Betty, who, for the dubious prize of a better conscience, wants to believe that whipped cream **is part of a healthy diet***.
> - *Consumers are confused by the broad spectrum of views on which foods are permissible **as part of a healthy diet**.*
> - *The GL Diet is based on eating certain carbohydrates, **as part of a healthy diet**, that slowly release energy keeping you going for longer, rather than storing the fuel away as fat.*
> - *Finally, limiting intake of free sugars to less than 10% of total energy intake **is part of a healthy diet**. And a further reduction to less than 5% of total energy intake is suggested for additional health benefits*

When there is the indefinite article in the prepositional phrase “part of”  it precedes an adjective

> - *We now acknowledge that food is more than the essential nutrients it contains and that NSP is **a necessary part** of a healthy diet.*
> - *Walnuts which contain the omega fatty acids are **a good part of** a healthy diet.*
> - …*Protein is **an essential part** of a healthy diet, especially when you're in ketosis. As a vegan, you need to make sure you include enough protein-rich plant-based foods in your meals.*
> - *Fruit is **a delicious part** of a healthy diet, and you should aim to eat at least 2 cups of fruit every day.*

All citations can be found in the first two pages in the link above.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/eating), Collins, RHK Webster's etc license this sense of eating: << **eating** [noun] ... (2)

food with reference to its quality or tastiness when eaten:
_This fish is delicious eating._ >> And 117 000 000 hits in a Google search for "healthy eating". Many of them refer to the diet / food rather than the act of eating.

Comment: P.S Nothing wrong with saying or writing about "healthy eating" that isn't my intention.

Comment: Replacing "healthy eating" with "healthy diet" actually clarifies whether I'd like to use the article or not. Thank you!

Comment: Google Books: [`"a part of a healthy diet"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+part+of+a+healthy+diet%22&tbm=bks) — no intervening adjective needed.

Comment: @TinfoilHat the string didn't deliberately exclude the indefinite article, and yet the citations I found are the ones listed in the answer. Why are there no instances of "a part of a healthy diet" in my search?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You're getting such a small result count because you've got the search set to exclude "very similar" results, and because Google stops showing results at around 400 even if you tell it not to exclude similar results. That 145 number isn't anywhere near a realistic count of actual hits.

Comment: (For comparison, my Google search results for "Mario" stop at 101 with "very similar" results excluded, and at around 400 with similar results included. There are *far, far* more than 400 web pages that say "Mario" on them.)

Comment: @user2357112 I give up with Google's algorithms and estimates. It makes these wild statistics which are impossible to verify. And I had no idea that Google stopped showing results after 400 webpages, it should say so.  I will never fully believe their number of hits and I'll stop visiting the last page in Google's results from now on.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you're right. In the past Google's result count is more aligned with what we normally expect, and in the past it's customary to use Google's result count this way. But now with advertisement and other prioritizing/ranking/filtering algorithms, it's no longer a useful statistics.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the article does make a difference. In this sentence, the article does not sound very idiomatic. One gets the idea that healthy eating is made up of parts, which is not a usual point of view; it seems more usual to think of healthy food as an uncountable part of healthy eating.

> ([*Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/part_1?q=part))
>
> *some*
>
> 1. [uncountable]
>    **part of something** some but not all of a thing
>    • We spent part of the time in the museum.
>    • Part of the building was destroyed in the fire.
>    • Part of the problem is that more and more people live alone.
>
> *piece*
>
> 2. [countable] **a section, piece or feature of something**
>    **part of something** • The mountains are covered with snow for a large part of the year.
>    • The early part of her life was spent in Paris.
>    • the latter part of the 19th century
>    • Making mistakes is an integral part of the learning process.
>    • We've done the difficult part of the job.
>    • an important/essential part of the project
>    • Wool production was a key part of the economy.

- Donuts are not  part of healthy eating.

Comment: Interesting. To me they sound equally good, but maybe I'm in the minority.

Comment: It sounds quite unidiomatic *without* the article to my AmE ear!

Comment: Hm, based on the other comments, looks like this is subjective! I can hear both possibilities sounding more natural — very gold/white or black/blue dress.

Comment: @rachelx Some subjectiveness, and even incertitude is at times involved in deciding which is preferable; there are cases where the use of "a" as opposed to that of zero article clearly make sense. ex.: "1/ The Federal law requires that the teacher in training either have had vocational experience or that she acquire it as a part of her training. 2/  It is an almost necessary part, too, of a teacher's preparation to go away from home for at least part of her training." It seems to me that in the first case a division into parts makes sense, but not in the second, where _a_ part is (1/2)

Comment: @rachelx  defined as a certain amount of time that might not coincide exactly with actual parts referred to as necessary (other necessary parts). In the case of eating or diets, using the article seems to give the idea of "component" (Doughnuts are not a component of healthy eating); this choice gives apparently to the term "doughnuts" a specificity that does not pertain to it. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Both versions (with "part" and with "a part") are fine. As [Cambridge notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/part) (with the "[U]" and "[C]" annotations), *part* can be used as either a count noun or a noncount noun, so it can be used with or without "a." Furthermore, there is no rule that says that the two things on either side of *to be* need to agree in number, or countability, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Eating is an action. Doughnuts are not actions. So the sentence is a bit weird.

I suggest instead:

- "Doughnuts are not part of a healthy diet"; or
- "Doughnuts are not associated with healthy eating".

The latter is also a bit less absolute.

Comment: 'Eating' does not refer solely to the process, Stef. **eating** [noun] ... (2) food with reference to its quality or tastiness when eaten: _This fish is delicious eating._ [Collins, etc]

Comment: "Doughnuts are not associated with healthy eating" is something that might be followed by "but believe it or not, they are actually good for you". Well, not in the case of donuts.